# Problemas al mostrar estilos css en la impresión de tabla en pdf con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un **html**, que al momento de apretar el botón `imprimir pdf`, me muestra todo el contenido de la tabla, pero se pierden los estilos *css*, al principio los tenia en un **css aparte** y solo llamaba a la clase, luego se los puse directamente para descartar.

```js
    function printdiv(printpage){
   

    var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
       var footstr = "</body>";
       var newstr = document.all[printpage].innerHTML
       var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
       console.log(headstr+newstr+footstr);
       document.body.innerHTML = headstr+newstr+footstr;
       window.print();
       document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
       return false;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
  <input type="button" class="boton-gris" value="Imprimir Formulario" id="create_pdf" onclick="printdiv('ContenedorContabilidad');" />
    <div id="ContenedorContabilidad">
    <!--  <a onclick ="ImprimePDF();" ><img src="../SiteAssets/img/pdf.png"/></a> -->
      <table id="tblContenedoraContabilidad" style="width:100%; border:0.5px; border-style:solid; border-color:silver;">
      <!--<table id="tblContenedoraContabilidad" class="tablaMateriales"> -->

        <tr>    
          <td>  
            <table style="width:100%">
            <!--<table class="tablaGenerica">-->

              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div id="divEncabezado">                    
                    <table style="width:100%">
                    <!--<table class="tblEncabezado">-->
                      <tr>
                        <td style="width: 20%;">Departamento originador:</td>
                        <td style="width: 45%;"><label id="nomDepOriConta" ></label></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="width: 20%;">APE N°</td>
                        <td style="width: 15%;"><label id="apeNumConta"></label></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="width: 20%;">Centro de beneficio:</td>
                        <td style="width: 45%;"><label id="centBeneConta"></label></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="width: 20%;">Fecha de emisión</td>
                        <td style="width: 15%;"><label id="fchFechaConta"></label></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <hr style="margin:0px 0px 10px 10px !important;background-color:#dcdcdc;border:none;height:1px;"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>Sírvase coordinar el retiro del siguiente 
                  material dado de baja</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table id="tblMaterialesContabilidad" style="width: 100%; border:0.5px; border-style:solid; border-color:silver;">
                  <!--<table id="tblMaterialesContabilidad" class="tablaMateriales">-->
                    <tr>
                      <!--<th class="thMateriales">Item</th>  para todas la misma clase -->
                      <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px;">Item</th>
                      <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px;">Cantidad</th>
                      <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px;">Unidad de Medida</th>
                      <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px;">Descripcion</th>
                      <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px;">Condicion</th>
                      <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px;">Valor Sugerido USD</th>
                      <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px;">Activo Fijo</th>
                      <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px;">Autorizador por SAP</th>
                      <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px;"></th>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <br/>
        <!--    <hr style="margin:0px 0px 10px 10px !important;background-color:#dcdcdc;border:none;height:1px;"/> -->
            <table id="tblFirmas" style="width: 100%; border:0.5px; border-style:solid; border-color:silver;">
            <!--<table id="tblFirmas" class="tablaMateriales">-->
            </table>
          <!--  <hr style="margin:0px 0px 10px 10px !important;background-color:#dcdcdc;border:none;height:1px;"/> -->
            <br/>
            <table id="tablaContabilidad" style="width: 100%; border:0.5px; border-style:solid; border-color:silver;" >
            <!--<table id="tablaContabilidad" class="tablaMateriales" >-->

              <tr>
                <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px; width:20%;" colspan="2" >Unidad Contabilidad</th>
                <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px; width:80%;" colspan="5" >Dirección de Abastecimiento</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px; width:10%;" colspan="1">Ítem</th>
                <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px; width:10%;" colspan="1" >N° activo fijo</th>
                <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px; width:30%;" colspan="2" >Destino</th>
                <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px; width:50%;" colspan="3" >Bodega</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="1" style="width:10%;"></th>
                <th colspan="1" style="width:10%;"></th>
                <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px; width:15%;" colspan="1" >Bodega</th>
                <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px; width:15%;" colspan="1" >Documento</th>
                <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px; width:16%;" colspan="1" >Acción</th>
                <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px; width:16%;" colspan="1" >Valor Sugerido USD</th>
                <th style="background:#F2F2F2; padding:3px; width:18%;" colspan="1" >Documento</th>
              </tr>
            </table>
          <!--  <hr style="margin:0px 0px 10px 10px !important;background-color:#dcdcdc;border:none;height:1px;"/> -->
            <table id="tblContabilidadObservaciones" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <th>Observaciones</th>
              </tr>
            </table>
          <!--  <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div id="buttons" class="botonera">
                    <input id="btnE" type="button" class="boton-gris" value="Guardar" onclick="GuardaContabilidad();"/>                  
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table> -->
          </td>  
        </tr>    
      </table>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Creo recordar que añadiendo el atributo `media="all"` en la etiqueta `<link />` preservas los estilos al imprimir.

Comment: ¿Lo solucionaste?

Comment: @MitsuG le puse el estilo en linea le quite el archivo css, igualmente tengo que poner el media="all"?
(estaba solucionando otras cosillas :) )

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Poner tus reglas CSS para la tabla dentro una `media print`.
2. Referenciar tu hoja de estilos y ponerle el atributo `media` en `all` o `print`.

La primera opción permite especificar *cómo se verá tu tabla* al imprimir. Cabe aclarar que las reglas dentro de un `media print` no afectan al documento en vista normal.

```
@media print {
  /* reglas */
}
```

La segunda opción es más práctica si quieres que tanto la vista normal como en la impresión tengan la misma apariencia.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="all"/>
```

---

Actualmente, solo Chrome permite imprimir con color dado por CSS. Esto es posible mediante la regla: `print-color-adjust: exact;`.

```
@media print and (color) {
   * {
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
}
```

Otra opción es convertir la página o región de ella en PDF y hacer que el usuario la imprima por su cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

yo traté de imprimir un archivo que contiene una tabla y le puse colores a las filas y columnas pero al momento de imprimir no reconoció los colores aun teniendo bien escrito los estilos.

Al momento de imprimir, existe una opción que dice "Mas ajustes", seleccionalá y abajo aparecerá una función que dice "Configuración". En ella hay dos casillas, una que dice "Encabezado y pie de página" y la otra "Gráficos de fondo".

En mi caso, no tenía seleccionada la segunda opción y solo así reconoció los colores de la tabla.